# ASUS fonepad 7 (K00Z) is giving an Upgrade. But is the new firmware safe to install?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, asus-padfone-t00c

I would like to know how safe is this upgrade? 'Cause I've heard many people ended up bricking their tablet after upgrading the firmware (like the gentlemen in [this forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/asus-fe170cg-bricked-t3048750)). So, I would like to know is the upgrade safe?

Also, what am I going to gain with this upgrade? What enhanced features does Kitkat has that Jellybean doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted ASUS support and they replied that the upgrade is optional. I did it anyway but didn't find any noticeable performance improvements/changes.